# Awk Solution:Extract XML data within a pattern

Tags: xml, awk

Am looking for an awk solution here. The xml file goes into gbs. min 4 to max 50gb!! Following is the sample xml structure of that file.

```
<mydata>
<item1>
  <abc>1</abc>
  <xyz>2</xyz>
  <lmn>3</lmn>
  <pqr>4</pqr>
  <pqr>5</pqr>
</item1>
<item1>
  <abc>1</abc>
  <pqr>2</pqr>
  <lmn>3</lmn>
  <jlk>4</pqr>
     <moredata>
       <pqr>6</pqr>
       <def>7</def>
     </moredata>
  <pqr>5</pqr>
</item1>
<item1>
<abc>1</abc>
<xyz>2</xyz>
<lmn>3</lmn>
<pqr>4</pqr>
<pqr>5</pqr>
```

What am trying to do are 2 things:

1. Trying to create a structure of the table with unique "columnnames". The unique nodenames across the pattern  are my columnames. Any node within a pattern that occurs once will be prefixed by "1". Anything that occurs more than once will be prefixed a number equivalent to its occurance. For e.g in this case the columnnames from the first pattern will be: abc1, xyz1, lmn1, pqr1, pqr2, moredata1, pqr3, def1. For the second it will be again abc1, pqr1, lmn1, jlk1, pqr2 and so on. After all the patterns are traversed the unique nodenames across patterns will be my columns of my table.
2. Creating insert commands for data within a pattern
   Once the structure is ready i want to create "insert into tablename set abc1="1",xyz1="2", lmn="3", pqr1="4", moredata1="",pqr2="5", def1="7"; for data within each pattern.

I aint so good with awk and the biggest challenge was my inability to prefix repetitive nodes within a pattern with numbers. The file is a 30G!!! behemoth xml. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Awk is the only solution I need. Tx.

Comment: Edit your question to show the desired output given the input you show. Do not assume we know what `nodenames across the pattern` means - it's all just rows and columns of text to us. Do you have an additional 30G available to store the output from the tool?

Comment: awk is not the best tool for this job. XML needs to parsed by an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

I think based on the xml format this will do what you need.  I'm assuming the "pattern" you mention is the `<item>` tags

```
awk -F"[<>]" -vq="\"" '
       $2~"/item"  {p=0;delete t;print line;line=sep="";next} 
       $2~"item"   {p=1;next} 
       p && $2!~"/"{line=line sep $2(++t[$2])"=" q $3 q;sep=","}
    ' file
```

will output

```
abc1="1",xyz1="2",lmn1="3",pqr1="4",pqr2="5"
abc1="1",pqr1="2",lmn1="3",jlk1="4",moredata1="",pqr2="6",def1="7",pqr3="5"
```

Comment: Tx @karakfa. I will check your script and let you know.

Comment: @Ed: The first awk create script should give me unique nodenames from the first <item1> to the last </item1> with the form and logic that I explained above: Create table t1(abc1 text, xyz1 text, lmn1 text ......);
The second awk insert script creates insert commands for this table:
Insert into t1 set abc1="1", xyz1="2",lmn1="3" ... for the first pattern and similarly for the other patterns.

Comment: Could you explain the lines please?

Comment: for each item block create a line representing name value pairs concatenated by comma. Using the field separator `<` and `>` leaves the tags and values in second and third position.  Extra logic to skip the end tag for parent tags (moredata in your case).  Additionally each tag is suffixed with the counter within each block.

Comment: Tx karakfa. I modified your script to get the insert query kinda of output going . Could u provide another piece which fill fit my distinct columnn name requirement? Something that will help me to create a table structure.  I gather it will involve some array manipulation to get the distinct values. Appreciate your help greatly so far.

Comment: aren't the names what you're looking for?  Just construct the part before the equal sign in line variable. Or it is something else?

Comment: Not just the names but unique names across patterns. Which means from your output above my column names will be abc1,pqr1,lmn1,pqr2,jlk1,moredata1,def1,pqr3,xyz1. It will be like putting the line variable value into an array and then picking the unique set out of it.

Comment: This is my output for your script: <br>

abc1="1",xyz2="2",lmn3="3",pqr4="4",pqr5="5" <br>
abc1="1",pqr2="2",lmn3="3",jlk4="4",moredata1="",pqr1="6",def2="7",pqr5="5" <br>
abc1="1",xyz2="2",lmn3="3",pqr4="4",pqr5="5" <br> . ... Not the one you printed.

Comment: Could you please look into this again?

Comment: Anyone else with a solution?

Comment: where are the `<br>` tags coming from?  There are not in your input! If they are there they need to be escaped as well.

Comment: OK, there was a typo changed `t[$1]` to `t[$2]` in the script.

Comment: Extremely grateful for your help. The one that nailed it for me was this line in your script $2(++t[$2]). For the rest I had made my own 'ugly' looking script which kinda did its job albeit longer. This tip helped greatly.